# No Persistence provider for EntityManager named - I am doing something wrong?

Tags: java

I have my persistence.xml with the same name, using toplink, under META-INF directory. Then I have my code calling it with...

```
public class DBConnect {
    @PersistenceUnit
    EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public DBConnect()
    {
        emf = null;
    }
    public void startConnection()
    {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory
                (
                    "cvut.fel.pjv.persistence.xml"
                );
    }
    public void closeConnection()
    {
        emf.close();
    }
    public EntityManagerFactory getEMF()
    {
        return emf;
    }
}
```

I have got the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named cvut.fel.pjv.persistence.xml
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at utils.DBConnect.startConnection(DBConnect.java:30)
    at utils.Server.<init>(Server.java:32)
    at utils.Server.main(Server.java:58)
```

Here are my persistence.xml - I think it should be right

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="cvut.fel.pjv_LibrarySystem_server_jar_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>model.Vydani</class>
    <class>model.Nosic</class>
    <class>model.Vypujcka</class>
    <class>model.Adresa</class>
    <class>model.Casopis</class>
    <class>model.Kategorie</class>
    <class>model.Kniha</class>
    <class>model.Nakladatelstvi</class>
    <class>model.Zamestnanec</class>
    <class>model.Ctenar</class>
    <class>model.Vytisk</class>
    <class>model.Autor</class>
    <class>model.SpisovatelePocetDel</class>
    <class>model.UzivateleAdresy</class>
    <class>model.Osoba</class>
    <class>model.DigitalniNosic</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://slon.felk.cvut.cz:5432/db18_koresmi1"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="db18_koresmi1"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="Hk2JsA"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And there is a pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>cvut.fel.pjv</groupId>
    <artifactId>LibrarySystem_server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.1212</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

I very much appreciate your help - I'm doing in netbeans as a maven project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument for `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory` is the name of the persistence unit. According to your `persistence.xml` your persistence unit is named *cvut.fel.pjv_LibrarySystem_server_jar_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU*. The following code should work:

```
emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("cvut.fel.pjv_LibrarySystem_server_jar_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU");
```